# Copy files from remote Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Im trying to create a cross-compilation job, that will build my code for both Windows & Linux.
I have set up Windows & Linux jenkins nodes, and configured two jobs, one with 'windows' label to run on my Windows machine and the other with 'linux' label to run on my linux machine.
I installed MultiJob plugin, and wrapped both jobs to run in parallel
When both finishes successfully, I want to copy all the generated files and do operations on them
In other words I want to copy the files from both jobs remote workspaces for further operations
Can anyone suggest a way how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

- Add your files to the artifacts in your child job (Using "Archive the artifacts" post-build step)
- In parent job add build step "Copy artifacts from another project", put you child job name and choose "Build triggered by current MultiJob build" in field "Which build"

Comment: Thanks. Making artifacts from my workspace means it keeps them per build on my host. Is it possible to remove them afterwards? Otherwise my disk space will drain quickly

Comment: It means that each build of the specific job will store the build artifacts on the Jenkins master (server). To resolve disk space issue you should set "Discard old builds" and define number of last builds you want to store (it may be 1)

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Only partialy. I want to keep my old build logs, but the product of each build is quite large so I upload it to remote storage, but would still like to keep the logs of my older builds